# Compiling multiple Java packages with TextMate

Tags: java, textmate, textmatebundles

I've recently been converted to TextMate as a diverse and powerful programmer's tool. But it appears to be lacking in Java support. So, I've been trying to mess around with the supplied Java bundle (Compile & Run) but it only contains one line:

```
javamate_bootstrap.sh
```

I can't find this file on my machine, but it appears to only work for simple Java classes (ie, classes not contained within a package).

First of all, why is TextMate so useless for Java programming, and secondly (and most importantly) : Does anyone know of a bundle I can use, or have instructions on how to create one for larger scale Java development in TextMate?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: File `javamate_bootstrap.sh` is located at `/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Bundles/Java.tmbundle/Support/bin/`

Answer (score 0):

> First of all, why is TextMate so useless for Java programming

Mostly because there are three free (free as in beer) java IDE's, [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/free_java_ide.html?gclid=CMPbvLbwp6sCFRpggwoddW-03A), [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) and [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) that almost all professional java developers use. Any one of them will give you all the functionality you want out of TextMate and much, much more. Given that, there's not much demand for java features in TextMate or BBEdit, or Notepad++, etc. That's not to say people don't use them. They definitely do, but not in a high enough volume to make it worth it to the maintainers to add features to make java development easier.